# I can't choose any choice which represents a binomial distribution (out of 3 possible choices)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The question and the choice set:**

> The binomial distribution with mean $3$ and variance $2$ is:
>
> [A.] $(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3})^{2 \to 9}$
>
> [B.] $(\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{6})^{2 \to 9}$
>
> [C.] $(\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{5})^{2 \to 9}$

**My attempt at solving:**

I formulated $np=3$ and $npq=2$ and divided these two equations which gave me $q=2/3$. Next, I calculated $p=(1-q)=1/3$. Finally, I plugged this value back in $np=3$ to get $n=9$.

**The part where I'm stuck:**

Are these choices a *recognized* way to represent a binomial distribution? If they're not could you please help me decipher their meaning?

Comment: It has to be A.

Comment: @Parcly That's correct, I chose A myself (as a guess). I'm interested in knowing more about that notation.

Comment: It definitely seems idiosyncratic. I'm too busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to represent probability distributions of *discrete* random variables is with their *[probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function)*.

The probability generating function for a binomial distribution of sucess rate $p$, failure rate $q$, and trial amount $n$, is $~\mathsf G(z)={(q+pz)}^n$.

Using the values which you found, you have: $~{(\tfrac 23+\tfrac 13z)}^9~$ which ... *somewhat* looks like answer $A$.

Perhaps the issue is a formatting error on the question sheet?